# Dynamic link in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, excel-formula

I have a link (a whole column) in my Excel sheet to another workbook, for example:

```
='S:\Monthly outputs\[Ouputs 201606.xlsx]Test'!AK17/'S:\Monthly outputs\[Ouputs 201606.xlsx]Test'!AK2
```

Every month, this column needs to be changed. Currently, it is done manually, causes many flaws, and next month it will turn from AK to KL.

For this, I created the "AK" in this case by concatenate char(65) and char(75), and I wanted to use the concatenated cell in the link by replacing the AK part. However, putting the link directly into the whole link part will mean that the part "Test'!AK17/" will turn into "Test'!BB2217/". I can't use the text formula (it's a link), so what can I do?

Comment: Is there a predictable pattern for the changes?  Or a pattern you could populate in a list on a separate sheet?

Comment: I can't see how you're doing the concatenate you're describing. If you want to use VBA you can base the formula on a button click or macro that will create the formula based on the cell location text string value in a cell you can edit.

Comment: Yes; 1 XLSX has to be updated by the other (source) XLSX. And every month the link to the source row just have to change 1 to the right. So lets say for January we need A5, for February we need row B5, March C5 etc. I thought it is simply done by creating a button where the user can pick the date, but how can I change the "Row part" in the link...? So  "Test'!AK17/" would be "Test'!AL17/"... Referring to the cell in which the date is provided just provided a dead link: "Test'!BB2217/" for example, if the right new date for the new month is situated in cell BB22...

Answer (score 0):

YOu can make up the link cell using split parts as demonstrated below.  I have used named cells for convenience.  I have split the link cell in 3 parts, part1:text before the cell (AK17), part2: AK17 and part3: text after AK17.  Part 2 can be dynamically created based on current date if you give a reference month (say May) and reference cell (AK17)

This is what I have in cells A1-A3

```
A1:'S:\Monthly outputs\[Ouputs 201606.xlsx]Test'!
A2: =ADDRESS(ROW(INDIRECT(refCol)),COLUMN(INDIRECT(refCol))+current-refMnth)
A3: /'S:\Monthly outputs\[Ouputs 201606.xlsx]Test'!AK2
```

`refcol` `refMnth` and `current` used in formula in cell A2 are named cells with value `AK17` for cell named `refcol`, `5`(may) for cell named `refMnth` and formula `=MONTH(TODAY())` in cell named `current`.  This will dynamically update cell A2 and current month changes (value in cell `current`).  Your link cell (A4)then can be created with indirect

```
A4: =INDIRECT(part1&part2&part3)
```

where part1, part2 and par3 are names for cells A1, A2 and A3, respectively.